# Derivation of expected value of sample variance

Tags: statistics, expected-value, means, continuous-variables

I am following a derivation of the sample variance but they have skipped over some steps. Can anyone explain them? $X_1,...,X_n$ are a random sample.

$$E(S^2)=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})^2\right]=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum[(X_i-\mu)-(\bar{X}-\mu)\right]^2=\cdots $$ $$\cdots =\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n[(X_i - \mu)^2-2(X_i-\mu)(\bar{X}-\mu)+(\bar{X}-\mu)^2]\right]$$ I understand the above steps but I cannot follow the next few steps.

$$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\sum_{i=1}^n[(X_i-\mu)^2-2n(\bar{X}-\mu)(\bar{X}-\mu)+n(\bar{X}-\mu)]$$

How does one get the factor of n in for the second term? Then from here I understand the rest of the derivation. It also states that this works for both discrete and continuous distributions with a finite variance. So does that mean if this was to be shown for a continuous distribution then you would follow the same steps but with an integral? Or you would just end up with the same answer?

Comment: Note that $\sum X_i=n\overline X$.

Comment: I edited your formatting to try to make it more readable...I don't think I changed any of your bracketing but the last expression isn't clear.  Which terms are inside the summation and which ones aren't? I would think that only the term dependent on $i$ is inside the sum, but that's not the way you have written it.

Comment: Even with a continuous distribution, the sample sized $n$ would be $n$ observed values, so no integration would be required to find the sample variance

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the formatting. The whole expression is within the summation as the next line (that I have not included but understand) multiplies each of the terms by $n$ and pulls them out of the summation - other than the first term which is reliant on $i$. I am trying to use your first comment to try and make sense of it as $X_i$ remains within the summation so I am not sure how exactly they used that result. Could you explain it a little further please?

Comment: Well, using the summation I wrote down initially you can evaluate a lot of terms in the sum...Though in that case there should be terms outside the sum.  For instance $\Sum (\bar X-\mu)^2=n(\bar X-\mu)^2$ but you seem to have lost the power of $2$ and, again, that term should no longer be in the sum.  So, I think there are some errors in that fornula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there appear to be some problems with the formula as written.  In particular, it seems that some of the terms which appear to be inside the summation should be outside of it.  And there appears to be at least one typo.  But, the algebra behind the formulas is clear enough...it's just a matter of writing everything out.

To do a portion of the sum:

$$\sum -2(X_i-\mu)(\bar X-\mu)=\sum \left( -2X_i(\bar X-\mu)+2\mu(\bar X-\mu)\right)=\cdots$$ $$\cdots =-2n\bar X(\bar X-\mu)+2\mu n(\bar X - \mu)=-2n\bar X^2+4n\bar X\mu-2\mu^2n=-2n(\bar X-\mu)^2$$

To stress:  that term must now be outside of the sum.

And, as mentioned in the comments, we easily see that $$\sum (\bar X-\mu)^2=n(\bar X-\mu)^2$$  but the formula appears to have lost the square and, again, that term would now be outside the sum.

Comment: Thanks for the clear steps, I managed to follow them. I will have to recheck the formula.